# Loopback4 `HasOneRepository.create()` constraints behaviour

Tags: loopback4

Lopoback4 `HasOneRepository` interface implements `create` function. Suppose I have a `User` model and a `Profile` model where `User` hasOne `Profile`. In the controller:

```js
@post('/users/{id}/profile', {
    responses: {
      '200': {
        description: 'User model instance',
        content: {'application/json': {schema: getModelSchemaRef(Profile)}},
      },
    },
  })
  async create(
    @param.path.number('id') id: typeof User.prototype.id,
    @requestBody({
      content: {
        'application/json': {
          schema: getModelSchemaRef(Profile, {
            title: 'NewProfileInUser',
            exclude: ['id'],
            optional: ['userId']
          }),
        },
      },
    }) profile: Omit<Profile, 'id'>,
  ): Promise<Profile> {
    return this.userRepository.profile(id).create(profile);
  }
```

Testing this endpoint, there are a couple of unexpected result:

1. Providing an `id` for non-existence `User` would still create an entry in the `Profile` table.
2. Calling this endpoint multiple times would create multiple entries in the `Profile` table for the same user which means `hasOne` is no longer true.

Is this the expected behaviour or am I missing something?. I'm using `mariaDB` and `"@loopback/core": "^5.1.1"` and `"@loopback/repository": "^6.1.3"`,

1. Create a new loopback4 application using `lb4` cli.
2. Create a mysql datasource
3. Create a new `User` and `Profile` models and repositories.
4. Create a `HasOne` relation between `User` and `Profile`.
5. Create the controllers.
6. Test POST: `/users/{id}/profile` with valid `id` and random `id`

Expect:

1. Throw ENTITY_NOT_FOUND error if user with `id` do not exists
2. Throw DUPLICATE error id `profile` for user with `id` alreadt exists.

Result:

1. The `profile` is created regardless if user with `id` exists or not
2. Multiple `profile` for `user` with the same `id` are created violating 'hasOne' relation
3. The this.userRepository.profile(id).get() would only return the first instance found